# MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have this code within my Query on MySQL now. I'm trying to use this on python, but when I'm doing

```
Query = ('SELECT price, book,
         FORMAT((price / book)*100,'P') as price_ratio 
         FROM book_db')
```

the python didn't accept the 'P,' how I should right this Query on python, so it will accept the `'P'` Thank you

Comment: this is a terrible way to ask a question, but lucky for you the solution is simple. replace your **outer** single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`

Comment: Please, use a text formatting, when post a question.

Comment: By the way, could you add a full snippet with your code. We even dont know what mysql module you use

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, this fixed the issue. I will make sure my question be more organized  next time,

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for string, if your line contains single quotes.
Details are https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/contributing/python.html#use-single-quotes